# Dojo Stack Container Startup hides the inner widgets

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, dojo, dijit.layout

Below is my code snippet, when I'm using dojo StackContainer, as soon as Stack container.startup is triggered, everything gets hidden except the title of the content panes. Please do let me know where I'm going wrong :

```
        var linkOamTp = new TitlePane({
            id:"linkOamTp",
            preventCache : false,
            open :true
        });
        registry.byId(containerWdg).addChild(linkOamTp);

        domConstruct.create("div",{id:"linkOamStackControllerDiv"},linkOamTp.containerNode);
        domConstruct.create("div",{id:"linkOamStackContainerDiv"},linkOamTp.containerNode);
        var linkOamSc = new StackContainer({
            style: "width: 100% !important; height: 98% !important",
            id: "linkOamStackContainer"
        },"linkOamStackContainerDiv");

        var cp1 = new ContentPane({
            title: "A-END",
            style : " width:100%; height: 100%; ",
            content : "content a"
        }); 
        linkOamSc.addChild(cp1);

        var cp2 = new ContentPane({
            title: "Z-END",
            style : " width:100%; height:100%; ",
            content : "content-b"
            });
        linkOamSc.addChild(cp2);

        var controller = new StackController({containerId: linkOamSc.id},"linkOamStackControllerDiv");
        linkOamSc.startup();
        controller.startup();
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that 'linkOamSc.id' is actually returning "linkOamStackContainer"?

Generally, StackController is used in conjunction with StackContainer (which you have done) and StackController uses id of the StackContainer.

Try changing your code to

```
var controller = new StackController({containerId: "linkOamStackContainer"},"linkOamStackControllerDiv");
```

Comment: Hi @Manjinatha : 
I tried that as well, but it's of no use. Is there any w/a for this?
And one more thing, when I create the DIV inside document.body, this issue is not reproducible, but I need the div to be there inside the title pane only

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution for this, I just called "linkOamSc.resize()"

Comment: Glad that you resolved it and thanks for posting the answer.